# How do I convert a list of grayscale images into RGB images using EBImage

Tags: r, image, image-processing, image-classification

I have a list of grayscale images.
They are stored in R via EBimage with the following code:

```
Normaltrain<-list.files(path="folderl",pattern='jpeg',all.files=T,full.names=T)

Normaltrainpics<-list()
for (i in 1:169) {Normaltrainpics[[i]]<-readImage(Normaltrain[i])}
```

They are stored as images with the following attributes:

```
Image
  colormode: Grayscale 
  storage.mode: double 
  dim: X Y 
  nb.total.frames: 1 
  nb.render.frames: 1
```

How do I convert all of these images into rgb, or at least give them the dimensions [x,y,3]? I have done a for loop with
`channel(Normaltrainingpics[[i]],'rgb')`
but dimensions remain the same. Thanks.

https://rdrr.io/bioc/EBImage/man/channel.html
According to this resource: "rgb" converts a Grayscale image or an array into a Color image, replicating RGB channels.

Answer (score 1):

`for (i in 1:150) {toRGB(Normaltrainingpics[[i]])}` seems to have done the trick.